# reload/ reset embedded swf on click

Tags: jquery, flash, embed

I have various flash movies in  tags on my page. Is there any way on click of a button (html) I can restart/ reload the embedded flash movie?

Im using:

```
<object data="flash/cvdb_video_cvdb_access.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flash_99674493" width="680" height="316">
<param name="movie" value="flash/cvdb_video_cvdb_access.swf">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</object>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery to take all the HTML from the previous `<object..` element, and just inject the html back into it, as there is no way to "reload" an individual element. you reload locations, and the entire dom, but you don't want that. you just want to reload your swf.

```
var obj = $("object#flash_99674493");
var orig = obj.html();

var restart = function() {
    obj.html(orig);
    alert("reloaded");
}
```

see ([this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTVFD/))

Comment: This did what I asked, although I have changed how I want to do this now but thank you

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can. Using your object `(... id="flash_99674493"...)` example you could:

```
var elem = $("#flash_99674493")[0]; 
elem.reload();
```

As you tagged your question, I am using `jQuery`.

Comment: I can find nothing to suggest that this would ever have worked.