# reload embedded swf in html page in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, actionscript-3, flash

I have a swf file embedded in a html page. I want to reload the swf file without refreshing the page.

There is a same problem asked here: [reload/ reset embedded swf on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505972/reload-reset-embedded-swf-on-click)

And I tried the accepted answer and it works in chrome:

```
var obj = $("object#flash_99674493");
obj.html(obj.html());
```

But it seems it doesn't work in IE. How to make it work in IE?

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject ? It contains special methods for addition and deletion of swf.

Comment: Why do you not handle the reset inside the swf itself?

Comment: @DenisKokorin Yes, I do. But I can't find the method to reload it. Could you be more specific? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.swf` is embedded with `<object>`, use `data` property:

```
document.getElementById('flash_99674493').data += '';
```

For ones embedded with `<embed>` use `src`:

```
document.getElementById('flash_99674493').src += '';
```

Adding the empty string to `data` or `src` causes their reload.

In IE we have to replace the object with the same one:

```
var o = document.getElementById('flash_99674493');
var n = o.cloneNode(!0);
o.parentNode.insertBefore(n, o);
o.parentNode.removeChild(o);
```

Comment: I've tried this approach, although it works just fine in Chrome/Safari, but it seems it doesn't work in IE. Could you improve this?

Comment: It does work, but another answer has been posted earlier, so I accepted that answer. Your code is clean and efficient, good job! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sefier, the accepted answer rewrites the object's child nodes. This approach won't work if you use `embed` or your `object` has no `param` child nodes. It's up to you which solution to consider the best answer and which to use J.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using regular JavaScript using a wrapper? I did a test with this working on old browser such as IE 9.

```
<!-- wrapper around your flash object -->
<div id="flash-content">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="200" height="200" id="SoundSpectrum2" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="SoundSpectrum2.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            ...
```

And then the JavaScript:

```
function reloadFlash() {
   var content = document.getElementById('flash-content');
   var currentArray = [];

   while (content.firstChild) {
      currentArray.push(content.firstChild.cloneNode(true));
      content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
   }

   currentArray.forEach(function(item) {
      content.appendChild(item)
   });
}
```